# Unable to send HTML File from Node.js Server

Tags: node.js

I have been trying with the following sample program?

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');
var io = require('socket.io');

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    console.log ("Connected..");
    var path = url.parse (request.url).pathname;
    console.log ("path is " + path);

    switch (path) {
     case '/':
        response.write ("Hello.. use connectme.html ");
        break;

     case '/test':

        console.log ("Hello insideo /test//");
        response.write ("Hello. test..");
        break;

    case '/sock.html':
        console.log ("sock.html..");
        response.writeHead (200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        fs.readFile(__dirname+path, function (error, data){
        console.log ("Data is .. " + data);
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        response.write(data, 'utf8');
        });
        break;

     case '/index.html':

        response.write ("Inside connect.em.html");
        break;

     default:
        console.log (" Hell. i am not suppoed to be here...");
        response.writeHead(404);
        response.write("Unable to Find this page..");
    break;

   } // Switch  
   response.end();
 });

server.listen(8765);
```

In Particular,

the below line doesn't seem to sending the html file from server to client:

```
console.log ("Data is .. " + data);
response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
response.write(data, 'utf8');
```

The HTML content is printed in the console. but in the browser nothing is displayed.

In sock.html, I just  have one div with paragraph with dummy content.

I am sure i am doing some subtle error. Kindly Guide!!!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're `end`ing the response before waiting for the `readFile` callback to execute. Writing to a `WritableStream` after it has been `end`ed is an error. Remove the `response.end` call at the end and replace the calls to `response.write` with `response.end(data, encoding);`

```
case '/sock.html':
        console.log ("sock.html..");
        response.writeHead (200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        fs.readFile(__dirname+path, function (error, data){
          console.log ("Data is .. " + data);
          response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
          response.end(data, 'utf8');
        });
        break;
```

Also, the call to `url.parse(request.url).pathname` is redundant since `request.url` already refers to the requested path (the path in the status line).

Comment: I tried, replacing response.write (data ) to response.end(data, 'utf8'), but still i do not see the html displayed in the browser.

Comment: Ha.. Looks like i need to remove response.end() at the end of this function, and introduce response.end() to each switch cases, and then it works. BTW, is it the right way to do it?

Comment: Using a framework such as `Express` or `koa` would be better since they handle URL routing and HTTP verbs among other things. Your application doesn't handle HTTP verbs and the `switch case` block may become very large after adding more routes.